# Получить данные с TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Вникаю в WPF и MVVM. С начало написал так:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAccountLogin.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAccountPassword.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Все поля должны быть заполнены!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        using (Cursor = Cursors.Wait)
        {
            using (AccountContext ac = new AccountContext())
            {
                Account account = new Account();

                account.login = txtAccountLogin.Text;
                account.password = txtAccountPassword.Text;

                ac.Accounts.Add(account);
                ac.SaveChanges();

                MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт " + account.login + " добавлен.", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

                txtAccountLogin.Text = "";
                txtAccountPassword.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Но потом понял что код не должен знать ничего о интерфейсе. Вопрос, мне нужно создать модель "account", наследовать его `INotifyPropertyChanged` сделать `event` изменений полей. Потом надо сделать `AccountViewModel` и в нем и дальше я не понимаю что дальше. По клику кнопки к чему мне обратиться что получить текст из контролов? Правильно ли я понимаю что из за события изменения биндинг будет контрола будет так же изменять и состояние свойства? Вот мой пример как сделал с `DataGrid`:

```
class Message: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string bulletinText { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}  

class MessageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Message Message { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    public MessageViewModel()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>
        {
            new Message{ author = "Федор Иванович", bulletinText = "Привет, как дела?", message = "Продам собаку", id = 154 },
            new Message{ author = "Меткий снайпер", bulletinText = "Сообщите номер накладной?", message = "Доставка овощей", id = 255}
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MessageViewModel();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,0,0" MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="От кого" Binding="{Binding Path=author}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сообщение" Binding="{Binding Path=message}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Превью объявления" Binding="{Binding Path=bulletinText}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Вот так отлавливаю событие клика:

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;

    int id = (grid.SelectedItem as Message).id;

    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
}
```

Как сделать в первой части моего вопроса?

Comment: наследовать от `INotifyPropertyChanged` надо только вьюмодели. Этот интерфейс служит для того, чтобы оповещать UI об изменении во вьюмоделях

Comment: Если вы нигде не вызываете `public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")` - то для чего вам этот метод вообще нужен? От того факта, что вы реализовали интерфейс, ничего не поменяется, если вы методами интерфейса не пользуетесь. Если он вам не нужен - удалите

Comment: `if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));` можно просто заменить на `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));`

Comment: Чтобы обрабатывать события из интерфейса, в MVVM присутсвуют команды.

Comment: В общем, хотя бы немножко ознакомьтесь с паттрном MVVM, поглядите примеры кода, а то вы так надолго тут застрянете.

Comment: `Но потом понял что код не должен знать ничего о интерфейсе.` - я вам больше скажу, в полноценном MVVM не уместны события (`Click`, `MouseDoubleClick` и др.), вместо их используют привязки к командам. Вот представьте, что у вас нету вообще интерфейса, вы пишете приложение, а другой человек, сидя в другом офисе разрабатывает без вашего кода интерфейс и всего один DataContext их должен связать - это вот правильный MVVM. Также `MessageBox` - их тоже так просто реализовывать не стоит, обычно создается интерфейс для таких целей. Ну а вообще, мне не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, при чем тут TextBox?

Comment: Вы когда работаете с контролом, отображающем коллекцию чего-либо, то во вьюмодели должны, как правило, создавать для этого контрола 2 свойства: 1) собственно сама коллекция, у вас это `ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }`, вы его привязываете `ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"` 2) для выбираемого в этой коллекции элемента ,у вас должно быть `public Message SelectedMessage {get: set;}` в set вызывающий  событие `PropertyChanged` и привязываемый `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMessage}"`. Тогда не придется писать `(grid.SelectedItem as Message).id;`.